# How to show double underscore '__' if any object property value is missing

Tags: javascript

As you can see I am printing object property values but I can't print double underscore instead of '__' missing property value.

```
function findAddress(obj){
let object = Object.values(obj);
for(let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    const objects = obj[i];
    if(objects[values] === object[values] == ''){
        return objects.obj[values] = '__' ;
        }
    else if(objects === object){
        object = objects;
     }
}
return object;
}
const output = {street : 10, house : '', society : 'Earth Perfect'};
const res = findAddress(output);
console.log(res);
```

I am trying to print object property values but, if any property value is missing I want to print double underscore '__' instead of missing value. This program is printing object property value but it didn't printing missing property value.

Comment: You can't just for-loop an object.

Comment: @Suvo I have answered the simplified code. Try that

Comment: Do a bit of debugging. Use your browsers devtools inspect facility to check the console for errors. Use console.log E.g. to see what obj.length gives you. Learn about JS objects versus arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can **simply achieve** this:

```js
function findAddress(obj){
  for(let property in obj){
    if(obj[property] === ''){
      obj[property] = '__';
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
const output = {street : 10, house : '', society : 'Earth Perfect'};
const res = findAddress(output);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate an object (it doesn't have `length` property by default and number keys). But you can get an array of an object's keys and reduce them to a new object with needed transformations:

```js
const findAddress = obj => 
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((r, key) => (r[key] = obj[key] === '' ? '__' : obj[key], r), {});

const output = {street : 10, house : '', society : 'Earth Perfect'};
const res = findAddress(output);
console.log(res);
```